# Notation of a pickup out of open vamp?

Tags: notation

How do I notate a pickup that only gets played on the last time a vamp is played?

For example:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/JTypL.png

I want the quavers in bar 2 to only be played as a lead in to bar 3.

Answer (score 1):

Do you expect the cue to be delivered on the 4th beat or on the start of the measure?   If the latter, then you can just make the vamp measure a whole rest, and the first following measure contain 3 rests and the two eighth notes.

If the cue is going to come on the 4th beat, then I might put a lightweight horizontal line/bracket over the notes with some text annotation like "on exit only" or "last time only" -- and make sure you write a fourth quarter-rest under them to satisfy the vamp itself.

Of course, if you can track down the score to any musical, you'll probably find methodologies used in published music  , in which case I'll be unmasked as the fool I am :-)

Comment: I’ve used “last time only” and put the note(s) in question in parentheses; the rest of that music is written as is; always seems so do the trick just fine.

Comment: Can you provide an example of such publish sheet music with that case? I want to see how it looks

Answer (score 0):

Bracket the noteheads and write “last time” or “last time only” above.